# Reqular Expression does not work in ASP.NET MVC2 Application

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a model with number of validation rule:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Number must be enter")]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]{1,10}$", ErrorMessage = "Your must be enter only integer number between 0-10 simvols")]
    public int Number
    {
        get { return number; }
        set { number = value; }
    }
```

so my validation does not work.I check my code, but can not find where I did wrong.
This is part of my view template:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   {%>
<%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
<div class="editor-label">
    <p class="number">
        Enter number</p>
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Number, new {@class = "txtNumber"})%>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Number) %>
</div>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate" class="button" />
</p>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not working?  Are you checking ModelState.IsValid in your post method?

Comment: Yes I am sure,, please look at this video:http://screencast.com/t/6vS1X12c9Sak

Comment: Why are you even doing it this way?  You should instead be using a model bound method.  If you make Number a nullable int, then instead of FormCollection have `int? Number` in your parameter list, then the value will be automatically bound and converted to an int.  You can add a Range validation to make sure it falls within the correct range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression should be this:

```
"^([0-9]|10)$"
```

EDIT:

Your real problem, however is that you aren't doing things correctly.  You are using an int type in your model.  But then you're using FormCollection in your Post action.  FormCollection bypasses the model binder, and gives you whatever is typed in.

You should instead be model binding your value, and you should be making it a nullable int in your model.  The reason is that int is a value type, and cannot be null.  Therefore, it must always contain a value, which in the case of you entering text means that value will be 0, and since 0 passes your validation, the `ModelState.IsValid` will return true.

Instead, do this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Number must be enter")]
[Range"^[0-9]{1,10}$", 
    ErrorMessage = "Your must be enter only integer number between 0-10 simvols")]
public int? Number {get;set;}
```

Then in your action method:

```
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
       // model.Number is now an integer already, and IsValid will be false for no number
    }
}
```

Comment: @ElvinArzumanoğlu - because your regular expression does not validate a number from 1-10 as your error message indicates.  It is any digit from 0-9, 1-10 times.

Comment: @ElvinArzumanoğlu - see update, also note that if you intend for it to take 10 digits, then you will overflow an `int` after `2,147,483,647`, which will cause you problems

Comment: What do you mean by "FormCollection bypasses the model binder"? Also a reference to support this would be appreciated.

Comment: @zespri - I mean that FormCollection will always contain whatever is in the posted values, regardless of whether or not they are of the correct type and pass validation.  ModelBinding happens after the FormsCollection is created.  Using my example above, Number will be null if you type in text, but FormsCollection["Number"] will contain the value entered.  You have to look at his screencast to see how he is doing his model binding.

Comment: @MystereMan, thank you for good answer and explanation. My code work well.

Comment: @ElvinArzumanoğlu please consider accepting the answer if it has helped you

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your elements are wrapped inside the html.beginform tags. Validations only work if your controls are inside <form> element.

Comment: Thank you Hitesh.Aneja. I know this,, I wrote html.beginform. But nothing happend.